# Intuition behind the orientation of arbitrary k-manifolds in arbitrary dimensions.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am wrestling with the intuition behind the definition of the orientation of a k-manifold in $R^n$.

The book that I am self-studying out of states that:

"Let M=**X**(D), where **X**: D $\epsilon$ $R^k$ $\Rightarrow$ $R^n$, be a smooth parametrized k-manifold. An **orientation** of M is a choice of a smooth, nonzero k-form $\Omega$ defined on M. If such a k-form exists, M is said to be **orientable** and **orientated** once a choice of such a k-form is made."

The book also states that:

"Let M=**X**(D), where **X**: D $\epsilon$ $R^k$ $\Rightarrow$ $R^n$, be a smooth parametrized k-manifold. The tangent vectors **T**$_{u1}$...**T**$_{uk}$ to the coordinate curves of M are said to be **compatible** with $\Omega$ if:

$\Omega_{X(u)}$(**T**$_{u1}$...**T**$_{uk}$)>$0$

We also say that the parametrization **X** is **compatible** with the orientation $\Omega$ if the corresponding tangent vectors **T**$_{u1}$...**T**$_{uk}$ are."

I know that this definition of orientability and $\Omega$ simplifies to defining the orientation of parametrized manifolds (k<2) using the directions of tangent and normal vectors. However, for k>2, is there any intuition behind this definition of orientability and $\Omega$?

(Let me know if the notation used in this question needs to be defined).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To integrate a differential form $\omega$ over a manifold $M$, you first chop up $M$ into tiny pieces $M_i$, in such a way that $M_i$ is (approximately) a parallelepiped spanned by tangent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$. To compute the contribution of the $i$th piece, you pick a point $p \in M_i$ and  plug the tangent vectors into $\omega(p)$. Then you sum up all these individual contributions to get the integral. Sounds great, right? *But when you plug $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ into $\omega(p)$, what order should they go in?* We need to make a consistent choice. That's why we need an orientation for $M$.

Comment: So, when plugging the tangent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ into $\omega(p)$, you would order them so that $\Omega(p)(v_1,\ldots, v_k)$ is positive. That way there is no ambiguity in our plan to "chop up the manifold, compute the contribution of each piece, then add up all the individual contributions" to compute $\int_M \omega$.

Comment: That makes sense. However, is the orientation k-form itself arbitrarily defined depending on the manifold? Or is there some consistent method of defining it?

Comment: I think you can show that if $M$ is connected then there are essentially only two choices for the orientation of $M$. In other words, I think that making a different choice of $\Omega$ would change the value of the integral by at most a minus sign. (I'm not an expert on this subject, so someone correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a topological point of view could be of use here.

A visual way to consider the orientation of any manifold is to imagine that you try to paint the manifold with two colors for each 'side'. More specifically, you consider the 2-fold orientation covering: locally you can orient as usual (as $\mathbf R^n$) and on the intersection you make orientations (colors) agree.

This 2-fold covering is connected if and only if the manifold is not orientable. Indeed, this means that there is a path that make you pass from the first color to the second. If the $2$-fold covering is not connected, then each color never meets the other: you can paint in blue all along a side without meeting the other side.

Now, from a differential point of view. You can still preserve this idea of painting. A $k$-form is a way to paint, with the colors $+$ and $-$. If $\omega$ is a local $k$-form then the space $\omega(X)>0$ can be distinguished from $\omega(X)<0$. Those are the two colors.

If you can find a global never vanishing $k$-form $\Omega$ then your manifold is oriented: take for example the color $\Omega(X)>0$ as in your book. Otherwise, there exists a path going from a color $-$ to $+$ meaning that any $k$-form will vanish.